# Get changes after merging datasets

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

Hello I have two Datasets with the same schemas and i need to get changes between two of them.

Datasets can be created using code below:

```
DataSet First = new DataSet("DSStore");
DataTable Footer = new DataTable("Footer");
DataColumn Column = new DataColumn("Value", Type.GetType("System.Int32"), "");
DataColumn[] PK = new DataColumn[1];
PK[0] = Column;
DataSet changes;
First.Tables.Add(Footer);
Footer.Columns.Add(Column);
Footer.PrimaryKey = PK;
//Clone to create second one
changes = First.Clone();
```

now just fill both with data:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     var row2 = changes.Tables["Footer"].NewRow();
     row2["Value"] = i;
     changes.Tables["Footer"].Rows.Add(row2);
}
var firstRow = First.Tables["Footer"].NewRow();
firstRow["Value"] = 8;
First.Tables["Footer"].Rows.Add(firstRow);
First.AcceptChanges();
changes.AcceptChanges();
```

Now when we have all data prepared we can get to what I tried:

I tried merging both of them:

```
First.Merge(changes);
if (First.HasChanges())
    Console.WriteLine("has changes");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Doesnt");
```

but unfortunately merge do not change row status so after rows being accepted hasChanges returns false and getchanges is null.

I tried another way:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> added = changes.Tables["Footer"].AsEnumerable().Except(First.Tables["Footer"].AsEnumerable(),DataRowComparer.Default);
Console.WriteLine("Added:");
foreach (var row in added)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row["Value"]);
}
```

Now i received some results but it is printing all 9 lines correct. So I tried to insert changes to the first dataset:

```
foreach(var row in added)
{
   changes2.Tables["Footer"].Rows.Add(row);
}
if (changes2.HasChanges())
   Console.WriteLine("has changes");
else
   Console.WriteLine("Doesnt");
```

But after trying to add rows I am receving `ArgumentException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change one line:

```
foreach(var row in added)
{
     changes2.Tables["Footer"].Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
}
```

now its ok. Adding lines creates changes